# Perform default on event object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have the following touchmove handler

```
var lastY = -1;
$('body').on({
    'touchmove' : function(event) {
        var currentY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
        if(lastY === -1) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if (lastY > currentY) {
            //Perform default here
        } else if (lastY < currentY) {
           event.preventDefault();
        }
        lastY = currentY;
    }
});
```

How can I perform the default or reenable this event if later in the touch I decide that I no longer want to prevent default?

Very importantly, I want to perform the default **on this exact event object** so merely unbinding the touchmove handler will not work because `event` will still have it's default turned off.

Comment: When exactly is "later" in this case? Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: Ok, I added a more complete example

Comment: The code as you have it should just work (assuming you assign something to `lastY` at some point). The `if` branches are mutually exclusive, so each branch will be executed only once for a single event instance. Meaning the `event` object for which `lastY === -1` is true, is a different one than the one for which `lastY > currentY` is true. So it doesn't make sense to talk about "turning on the default behavior" because you never turned it off on the first place.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing something here: Whenever `touchmove` is triggered, you get a new `event` object.

Comment: @Felix Kling Are you saying that everytime my handler is called it is a new event object even if it's still the same touch? (Long swipe for example)

Comment: @Juhana You are correct.  I just mader a mistake while typing this code into StackOverflow.  Fixed.

Comment: Yes, at least that happens for `mousemove`. It's just an event that constantly triggers while the mouse moves. The concept of "long running" events doesn't fit into the DOM event model IMO (with bubbling and capture phases).

Comment: @FelixKling You are correct.  It is a different object.  Then the real question is why the browser doesn't scroll when I don't preventDefault (after preventingDefault in the past)? Do you know if there is anything special about the first touchmove event?